# Windows installer for office add in

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, ms-office, office-addins

I created s set up project using [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx).

The addin was not getting installed. When I tried to add it through add ins in excel it said `"xxx is not a valid office addin".`

This error is because the dll is not strong named and not in GAC. So I enabled adding the dll in GAC in the set up project using [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;324168&x=9&y=14)

I am still not able to see the add in when I run the set up. and when I forcibly tried to add it, got the same error.

Any idea whats going wrong?
Thanks in advance!

**Update:** Added the registry entry in the deployment project

[image]

Comment: Go over your setup project again (combined with that link) and very carefully review if you have it all exactly the same. There should n't be a need to put the dll in the GAC. The error is not because it's not in the GaC the error is because the install isn't 100% correct or you are missing prerequisites. Have a look at the discussion at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/8272d4b6-d263-46f8-9387-72c637e97b66/ and especially check if you have the registry keys that you need

Comment: @Eddy I have gone through Saurabh Bhatias blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/08/deploying-your-vsto-add-ins-to-all-users-saurabh-bhatia.aspx and checked. It still doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Can you update with some more info: Are targeting office 2010? What is actually in the registry after you do the install on the target machine? Is your add-in listed at all in the add-ins list after installing and just not loading or isn't it present at all? Make sure to also check if the add-in isn't listing in the "disabled items" (it might have ended there if there was an error during loading). What happens if you add the registry keys not to HKLM but to HKCU (install not for all users but only for current one which requires less security wise)

Comment: @Eddy office2007, addins not listed at all.HKLM or HKCU results the same

Comment: Some more longshots I can come up with. I doubt this will give you anything but make sure you don't suppress vsto errors (See the last paragraph in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms269003(v=VS.100).aspx about VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS and VSTO_LOGALERTS) You can look at this msdn troubleshooting guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s0wczt9 And the final thing that I can see is that your add-in registry key starts with a . mine are formatted as <companyname>.<addinname> Really no clue if that has anything to do with it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FInally used clickonce to create the build!!