# click once publish for office add in

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, clickonce, add-in, setup-project

in continuation with trying to create setup for excel add in using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945603/windows-installer-for-office-add-in), I am trying to use clickonce.

When I publish, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred generating a bootstrapper: Unable to begin updating resource for bin\Release\app.publish\setup.exe with error 800700C1
```

I am using VSTO, VS2010, target .net framework 3.5 and office 2007.

Any cline

Comment: Priya, did you ever find an answer to this? I am having the same problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you search the web for the error code.  Possibly "800700C1 ClickOnce"?

Try [this MSDN solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/e81d47d9-5df6-49b9-84b4-7bdbe77d3eaa).  This post also links to multiple options for solving this bug.  If the first doesn't work, try something else on the list.